# Issue with schedule send mass sms in civicrm

Tags: php, wordpress, civicrm

I have a problem with civicrm in wordpress.
when create a mass sms schedule with activation date, Sms send immediate

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not stating the problem itself.
However, the solution may be to activate the scheduled job "Send scheduled SMS"